# Filter Kendo DataSource by date range

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, filtering

I'm currently trying to filter a Kendo DataSource by using a Kendo DropDownList and it's not working as I had expected it to.

I have a Kendo DropDownList that has a few options in it that allow the user to filter the DataSource by 1, 3, 6, 9, or 12 months. I'm also using `moment.js` to handle the adding of months to the current date.

Here is my DropDownList `onChange` event:

```
onMonthRangeChange: function (e) {
    var value = e.sender.value();
    switch (value) {
        case "1":
            var oneMonth = moment().add(1, "month");
            var firstOfMonth = moment().startOf("month");
            viewModel.myTaskDataSource.query({
                logic: "and",
                filters: [
                    { field: "DueDate", operator: "gte", value: firstOfMonth },
                    { field: "DueDate", operator: "lte", value: oneMonth }
                ]
            });
            break;
        case "3":
            // similar to above code except for 3 months
        case "6":
            // similar to above code except for 6 months
        case "9":
            // similar to above code except for 9 months
        case "12":
            // similar to above code except for 12 month
    }
})
```

Although I thought this would work, it doesn't. Instead it just shows everything in the DataSource. I even tried changing `viewModel.myTaskDataSource.query` to `viewModel.myTaskDataSource.filter` but then I just get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function - kendo.all.js:1129

I also suspected that maybe it was because Kendo and moment.js were using different time formats but even after parsing all of the kendo dates to moment dates I get the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, I was finally able to find a solution!

I looked more closely at the error and noticed that it mentioned something about `kendo.parseDate` so I knew there was some issue with the dates that was causing the filtering to not work.

I simply added `toDate()` onto the end of my `moment.js` date objects and now it all works as expected!

My filtering now looks like the following:

```
onMonthRangeChange: function (e) {
    var value = e.sender.value();
    switch (value) {
        case "1":
            var oneMonth = moment().add(1, "month").toDate();
            var firstOfMonth = moment().startOf("month").toDate();
            viewModel.myTaskDataSource.filter({
                logic: "and",
                filters: [
                    { field: "DueDate", operator: "gte", value: firstOfMonth },
                    { field: "DueDate", operator: "lte", value: oneMonth }
                ]
            });
            break;
        case "3":
            // similar to above code except for 3 months
        case "6":
            // similar to above code except for 6 months
        case "9":
            // similar to above code except for 9 months
        case "12":
            // similar to above code except for 12 month
    }
})
```